# Sample IOS Application to Compare Between Similar Applications Written in Different Languages

Tags: ios, objective-c

Having solid experience with Javascript, C#, SQL and NodeJS; among other languages. I wanted to know if there exists a `TODO` sample application, similar to what currently exists with [`TODO MVC`](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc)?

This would go a long way in helping me understand `Objective-C` and how its constructs, patterns and app development workflows relate to that of `C# .NET`, `Javascript` \ `NodeJS` and other languages.

Comment: Have you looked at the [iOS sample code library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/) from Apple? Or the [WWDC 2015 Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/)?

Comment: nope, but thanks for the advise. will do so now...